# How to access GIT commit in iOS app using Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git, git-commit

[image]

I am using Swift 4 I want to grab the first 6 letters of `git commit` and display in my **iOS** app.

The command to get that is

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

**How do I get that working in swift  ?**

I'm opening to any suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

You will not be able to access your development environment from the app.

However, you could add a `Run Script Phase` to your project's Build Phases that reads this value at build-time, then injects it into the final binary.

```
MY_GIT_HASH=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
```

Then in your source somewhere (pseudocode, not swift-compliant):

```
my_version_string = "Version: " + MY_GIT_HASH
```

I do recommend against doing this, though. Instead, you should be using regular version numbering (x.y.z) and tagging each released build. This way, you can quickly scan through your git repo for tags to see which git commit relates to which version number.

Version numbers are also much more meaningful to end users than git hashes because they provide some modicum of temporal relation: they're always increasing.